# Minimal instalation CentOS USB modem LTE internet doesn't work

Tags: centos, usb, dhcp, modem

I am using a Huawei USB stick. Unfortunately I cannot connect to the Internet. It's a problem somewhere in DHCP, I guess, but I don't know.

Could somebody help me?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like NetworkManager is trying to operate the LTE modem like a generic wired NIC, and trying to request an IP address by DhCP immediately.

But a LTE modem needs a bit more preparation than that: it may need to be told to connect to a particular network, and maybe fed a PIN number to unlock the (U)SIM card, if applicable. All these things can be handled by ModemManager, that works as an add-on to NetworkManager.

You don't seem to have ModemManager installed: it covers various 3G/LTE modems and the various vendor-specific control protocols they use. Install it, then use `mmcli -L` to verify the modem is detected. The detection and initialization of the modem can take a moment or two.